# loop through multiple query in mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql

I have want to run through multiple queries inside a for loop.

my code looks like this:

```
ES4 = """
select 
  *,
  SUBTIME(TIME(end_time),TIME(start_time)) as duration
from rents
where kickscooter_id
in (select kickscooter_id
    from kickscooter_control_units
    where particle_product_id
      in (9358, 9383))
    AND
    start_time between DATE('2019-11-05') and DATE('2019-11-06');
"""
 --- on separate box/cell in jupyter notebook
M365 = """
select 
  *,
  SUBTIME(TIME(end_time),TIME(start_time)) as duration
from rents
where kickscooter_id
in (select kickscooter_id
    from kickscooter_control_units
    where particle_product_id
      in (7915, 8593, 8863, 8942, 9355, 9356))
    AND
    start_time between DATE('2019-11-05') and DATE('2019-11-06');
"""

versions = [ES4, M365, PRO]
version_names = ["ES4", "M365", "PRO"]

for version, name in zip(versions, version_names):
    df = pd.read_sql(version, con=conn)
    df["duration(s)"] = df["duration"].apply(lambda row: row.total_seconds())
    df_error = df.loc[(df["duration(s)"] <= 45) | (df["duration(s)"] >= 7200)]
    df_okay  = df.loc[(df["duration(s)"] > 45) & (df["duration(s)"] < 7200)]

    print(f'{name}: {len(df)}')
```

This give `DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql:myquery (0,'') unable to rollback`

The only thing that changes in each query is list in "in" clause, I've tried changing only that part by creating a list and changing them to tuples however it did not work so I am using the method I have shown above. Is there a way to do this? I do not want to write same code multiple times for multiple queries.

Comment: What do you mean by "on separate box"?

Comment: one query in one cell and other in another cell

Comment: ok, I thought "separate box" might mean a different computer.

Comment: nope, sorry for the confusion, I've fixed it

Comment: Is that really the entire error message? It doesn't show the MySQL error message?

Comment: that message and my query

Comment: Is `PRO` similar to the two queries you show?

Comment: @Barmar Yes same except different number for particle_product_id

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like `pd.read_sql()` is making it difficult to see the actual MySQL error. I'm not sure how to get around that.

Comment: But when I look at other questions about that error message, it's always followed by the actual text of the failing SQL query. Does it actually have the words `myquery (0, '')` in the error message, or was that you simplifying the error message?